# Google sheets одной формулой два столбца

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Подскажите пожалуйста, какой формулой можно вытащить из таблицы два столбца, например A и H, при этом желательно отфильтровать из вывода пустые ячейки?

Что-то типа

```
=QUERY(Transposed!A:H; "where Col2 is not null"; 1)}
```

Только рабочее ))

Данные и текстовые и цифры

Такой вариант не прокатывает ((

```
=query(E1:F;"Select * where F is not null OR where F <>''";1)
```

Comment: А пример на листе? Гадать, может, кому и итересно, но при наличии примера решение можете получить гораздо быстрее

Comment: @vikttur https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1znmlRQpKgKSNeEb2zzl9USg_IeoYLjVG7HH1pYFBHdc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: *Вывести только A:D* - непонятно, какие столбцы подразумеваются - с исходной таблицы или те, что показаны в результате выгрузки? Есл отойти от столбцов- что нужно? Получить количество товаров Ивана или получить перечень товаров? Какой смысл показывать лист с Вашей формулой? Покажите в таблице правильный результат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый лучший способ - использовать конкатенацию диапазонов

```
=QUERY({DB!A:A\DB!D:D};"select * where Col2 is not null";1)
```

`QUERY` - нелучшая функция для плохих неприведенных данных. [Проблема смешанных типов в QUERY](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XIHJZ7_cYZWeAtrLRQZQHYl_kBPaO3YxIYm_boUwfzc/edit?usp=sharing). Возможно, `FILTER` будет надежнее

```
=FILTER({DB!A:A\DB!D:D};DB!D:D<>"")
```

Comment: И снова вы меня спасли ))) Как раз то, что нужно! А есть ли какой-то волшебный способ размножить эту формулу в столбик? Сейчас прикреплю файл

Comment: Лучше сделать новый вопрос. Никто не заругает, а остальным будет проще разбираться в переписке. И да, пример был бы кстати.

Comment: А есть ли какой-то волшебный способ размножить эту формулу в столбик?
[Пример](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kUk8waxcGjzOX6wOIWF9qgQPU8Au5dLln08-HgpBUQs/edit?usp=sharing) А если получится сделать как на странице с названием "Реально ли?" то я наверное поверю сразу во всех богов )))) Макросы штука конечно хорошая, но я не уверен что смогу в них разобраться, если это не будет конечно совсем уж простой код. Мне и с формулами то тяжело да и время поджимает.

Comment: создал новый вопрос :) Пока не знаю какие уведомления тут приходят а какие нет, поэтому тегаю вас на всякий случай )

Comment: Вставить заголовок реально, конечно. Просто при подготовке данных добавьте колонку с заголовками в нужное положение, т.е. до "Отметка времени".