# Google sheets разложить столбцы на блоки

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Вопрос - продолжение [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1100982/google-sheets-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0)

А есть ли какой-то волшебный способ размножить эту формулу

```
=FILTER({DB!A:A\DB!D:D};DB!D:D<>"")
```

в столбик? [Пример](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kUk8waxcGjzOX6wOIWF9qgQPU8Au5dLln08-HgpBUQs/edit?usp=sharing) страница "Результат"

А если получится сделать как на странице с названием "Реально ли?" то я наверное поверю сразу во всех богов ))))

Макросы, которые вы предлагали в одном из ответов, штука конечно хорошая, но я не уверен что смогу в них разобраться, если это не будет конечно совсем уж простой код. Мне и с формулами то тяжело да и время поджимает.

Comment: @contributorpw задал новый вопрос (ответ) в том треде, но его удалили. Видимо я не правильно понял вашу рекомендацию )

Comment: Не думаю, что возможно разложить эту формулу без скриптов.